# ISagaDbContextFactory implementation for StructureMap

Tags: entity-framework, structuremap, masstransit, saga

Is there an implementation of ISagaDbContextFactory for StructureMap? I've seen an implementation of **AutofacSagaDbContextFactory** for Autofac, and I would write my own for StructureMap, but I don't know what payload to look for to get an instance of the **nested** container that I would have expected masstransit to have created?? I tried the following with no luck

```
public class StructureMapSagaDbContextFactory<TSaga> : ISagaDbContextFactory<TSaga> where TSaga : class, ISaga
{
  ...
  public DbContext CreateScoped<T>(ConsumeContext<T> context) where T : class
  {            
    if (context.TryGetPayload(out IContainer container)) // I don't know what to look for in the payload
      return currentScope.GetInstance<MyDbContext>();

    return Create();
  }
  ...
}
```

MyDbContext is registered as scoped with my container, and so would like a new instance per saga instance scope, i.e. similar to DbContext instance per web request if it were a web app, but for masstransit saga in this instance.

**UPDATE**: The ContainerSagaDbContextFactory class solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify which MassTransit version you were using, but the recommended way to set this up since MassTransit 6.1 is to use the `AddDbContext` method in the container integration package (which should be [MassTransit.StructureMap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.StructureMap/) in your case). You can see an example here: https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/efcore.html#container-integration.

Snippet from that webpage:

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddSagaStateMachine<OrderStateMachine, OrderState>()
        .EntityFrameworkRepository(r =>
        {
            r.ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Pessimistic; // or use Optimistic, which requires RowVersion

            r.AddDbContext<DbContext, OrderStateDbContext>((provider,builder) =>
            {
                builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, m =>
                {
                    m.MigrationsAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
                    m.MigrationsHistoryTable($"__{nameof(OrderStateDbContext)}");
                });
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Yes, the new integration is the best approach. There is an all-container context factory that is used under the covers in the GitHub repository.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Patterson, I did find that all container context factory you're talking about after looking through the masstransit code. Works as expected now, thank you very much